# Pre-populate node creation form based on "base" node

Tags: 7, entities

I have this content type "education course" where I set the title, description, evaluation type , duration and objectives(and so on). 
I want to create another content type "course edition" that would work this way : when I want to create an edition, I would choose what "course" I want to pick what "course" node to use, so it will pre-populate with the values that never change between editions.

How can I achieve this behavior?